# How can I Translate Mips instructions?

Tags: assembly, mips32

How can I translate the following instructions in native assembly language and in machine language code in hex form:

```
bgti $s0,-7,-20:  # branch if greater than immediate
divi t1, t3,2^22: # divide by immediate
```

I could not solve it because I could not find opcode or neither function code for these instructions.

Answer (score 2):

These are not part of the MIPS assembly language but are pseudo-instructions that are translated into multiple instructions. Therefore you would have to turn `bgti` into some combination of `li` and `bgt` and you can go from there.

Comment: li isn't pseudo intruction iteself?(just not sure)

Comment: @SergioOcchial Yes it is, however I think that it is commonly supported assemblers so you can put it in directly